# SQL 2019: Getting a Error: 14151, Severity: 18, State: 1

Tags: replication, sql-server-2019, errors, error-log, server

I created new replication servers for a Cisco Publisher/Subscriber Attendant Console. However, the replication is not working correctly. When I look at the logs on the Publisher side, I get error messages for spid62 and spid77:

> ```
> Error: 14151, Severity: 18. State: 1.
> ```

I already installed OLE DB Driver for SQL Server but it I'm still getting the same error.

> ```
> Message
> Date      2024-01-02 11:22:57 AM
> Log       SQL Server (Current - 2024-01-02 11:48:00 AM)
> Source    spid62  
> Message
> Replication-Replication Snapshot Subsystem: agent ATTCONADV1-ATTLOG-ATTCONADV1_ATTLOG-2 failed. 
>                                             The replication agent had encountered an exception.
> Source: Replication
> Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ReplicationAgentException
> Exception Message: An unspecified error had occurred in the native SQL Server connection component.
> ```

Any insight on how to fix this error?